# Delete confirmation with sweet alert 2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sweetalert2

I want to delete a DB record with php. Before I sumbit a form I want a notification of Sweet Alert (2) with the buttons "Yes of No".

When "yes" I want to submit the form and activate my php code.

Problem is it won't work. After I click "yes" my page is refreshing and my php code don't start.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="right gap-items-2">
        <button class="btn btn-error" name="archive" type="submit" onclick="archiveFunction()">archive</button>
    </div>
</form>


<script>
    function archiveFunction() {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit
        var form = event.target.form; // storing the form
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                form.submit();
            }
        })
    }
</script>


if (isset($_POST['archive'])){

$message = "test";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Modify the form button using an ID like this :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="right gap-items-2">
        <button class="btn btn-error" name="archive" type="submit" id="submitForm" >archive</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And then the script like this :

```
<script>
    $('#submitForm').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).parents('form');
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {

                form.submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I applied it but unfortunately it doesn't work. He doesn't want to reach my PHP.

Comment: What is the target php file path? if you didn't specify the address, it will post the form data to the current address

Answer (score 2):

```
##php/file:##
     <?php
                $no = 1;
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM office_info";
                $query = $conn->query($sql);
                while ($rows = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo
                        "<tr>
                                    <td>" . $rows['id'] . "</td>
                                    <td>" . $rows['office_name'] . "</td>
                                    <td>" . $rows['office_type'] . "</td>
                                    <td>" . $rows['office_address'] . "</td>
                                    <td>" . $rows['office_cont_person'] . "</td>
                                    <td>" . $rows['office_con_mobile_no'] . "</td>
                                    <td>" . $rows['office_start_dt'] . "</td>
                                    <td>" . $rows['office_end_dt'] . "</td>
                                    <td>
                                    <a href='office_info_edit.php?id=" . $rows['id'] . "' target='_blank' class='btn btn-success btn-sm><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>Edit</a>
                                    <a href='office_info_delete.php?id=" . $rows['id'] . "' target='_blank' class='btn btn-success btn-sm><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>del</a>
                                    <a data-id='" . $rows['id'] . "' id='delete_id' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' href='javascript:void(0)'></span>delete</a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>";
                }
                ?>
##script##
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on('click', '#delete_id', function(e) {
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                SwalDelete(id);
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });

        function SwalDelete(id) {
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "It will be deleted permanently!",
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
                showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                preConfirm: function() {
                    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                        $.ajax({
                                url: 'office_info_delete.php',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: 'id=' + id,
                                dataType: 'json'
                            })
                            .done(function(response) {
                                Swal.fire('Deleted!', 'Your file has been deleted.', 'success')
                            })
                            .fail(function() {
                                Swal.fire('Oops...', 'Something went wrong with ajax !', 'error')
                            });
                    });
                },
            });
        }
    </script>
    **office_info_delete.php**
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        require '../database.php';
        $id = intval($_POST['id']);
        $deleteQuery = "delete from `office_info` where id='$id' limit 1";
        $conn->query($deleteQuery);
        if ($conn->affected_rows == 1) {
            $response['status']  = 'success';
            $response['message'] = 'Product Deleted Successfully ...';
        } else {
            $response['status']  = 'error';
            $response['message'] = 'Unable to delete product ...';
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your answer to add some explanation and details. While it might answer the question, just adding some code does not help OP or future community members understand the issue or solution.

Comment: Yes I will add details

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#deleteamc').on('click',function(e) {
    
    event.preventDefault();
var form = this;
    
        swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "All data related to this AMC ID will be parmanently deleted",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, DELETE it!",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
   form.submit();
   } else {
    swal("Cancelled", "AMC Record is safe :)", "error");
 
  }
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST" id="deleteform">
        <input type="hidden" name="amccode" id="amccode" value="<?php echo $row['amccode']; ?>">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteamc" name="delete" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                Delete
        </button>
</form>
<!-- USER CONFIRM DELETE THEN FIRE DELETE FUNCTION -->

<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['delete']))
   {
   $amccode=$_POST['amccode'];
   
  
   echo "WRITE DELETE SQL CODE";
   exit;
 
     
   
   ");
?>
    
    <script src="../source/alert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/alert/dist/sweetalert.css">
    
<script type="text/javascript">
function SuccessSaved (){
 
        swal({ 
              title: "Success",
              text:  "All Records Successfully Deleted. Customer ID <?php echo $amccode ?>",
              type: "success",
     
        },
             function(){
               
   window.location.href = "<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/admin/amcall.php";
        });
}

</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
        $( document ).ready(function() {
   //console.log( "ready!" );
   SuccessSaved();
  });
  
  
</script>

  <?php  
   }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one , I used this in laravel , It works

```
<td>
                                                <form class="archiveItem"
                                                      action="{{route('archive.destroy',['id'=>$archive->id])}}"
                                                      method="Post">
                                                    {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                                                    {{csrf_field()}}

                                                    <input type="hidden" name="archive">
                                                    <a onclick="archiveRemove(this)" class="deleteRecord"
                                                       id="{{$archive->id}}"
                                                       style="cursor: pointer"><i class="fa fa-trash"
                                                                                  style="font-size: 20px;color: #000"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                </form>
```

and in scripts:

```
function archiveRemove(any) {
        var click = $(any);
        var id = click.attr("id");
        swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure !',
               text: "?????",
               type: 'warning',
               showCancelButton: true,
               confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
               cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
               confirmButtonText: 'yes!',
               cancelButtonText: 'no'
        }).then(function (success) {
            if (success) {
                $('a[id="' + id + '"]').parents(".archiveItem").submit();
            }
        })
    }
```